# dar valores a un drop-down list

Tags: jsp

Hola todos soy muy nueva en esto lo que me pasa es que tengo un formulario jsp que tiene un drop-down list y cuando lleno todo el formulario en la base de datos en ese campo guarda 0 y quiero que me guarde el valor que yo le asigno. Ayuda por favor

el campo perfil es el drop-down list

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String perfil_r = request.getParameter("perfil_r");
    String nombre_r = request.getParameter("nombre_r");
    String apellido_r = request.getParameter("apellido_r");
    String numeroid = request.getParameter("numeroid");
    String cargo_R = request.getParameter("cargo_R");
    String correo_r = request.getParameter("correo_r");
    String celular_r = request.getParameter("celular_r");
    String nombrecompa_r = request.getParameter("nombrecompa_r");
    String nit_r = request.getParameter("nit_r");
    String direccion_r = request.getParameter("direccion_r");
    String telefono_r = request.getParameter("telefono_r");
    String nombreU_r = request.getParameter("nombreU_r");
    String contraseña_r = request.getParameter("contraseña_r");

    consultas co = new consultas();

    if (co.registrar(nombre_r, correo_r, nombrecompa_r, direccion_r, apellido_r, cargo_R, nombreU_r, contraseña_r, 0, 0, 0, 0)) {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
     if(perfil_r.equals("1")){
         out.println("GERENCIA");
         }if(perfil_r.equals("2")){
         out.println("CLIENTE");
         }if(perfil_r.equals("3")){
         out.println("EMPLEADO");
         }
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("MENU.jsp");
    }

public boolean registrar(String NOMBRE_R, String CORREO_R, String NOMBRECOM_R, String DIRECCION_R,
            String APELLIDO_R, String CARGO_R, String ID_NOMBREU, String ID_CONTRASEÑA,
            int PERFIL, int IDENTIICASION_R, int CELULAR, int NIT) {
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    try {
        String miusuario = "insert into REGISTRO ( PERFIL, NOMBRE_R,IDENTIICASION_R,CORREO_R,NOMBRECOM_R,DIRECCION_R,APELLIDO_R,CARGO_R,CELULAR,NIT,ID_NOMBREU,ID_CONTRASEÑA)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        stm = getConnection().prepareStatement(miusuario);
        stm.setInt(1, PERFIL);
        stm.setString(2, NOMBRE_R);
        stm.setInt(3, IDENTIICASION_R);
        stm.setString(4, CORREO_R);
        stm.setString(5, NOMBRECOM_R);
        stm.setString(6, DIRECCION_R);
        stm.setString(7, APELLIDO_R);
        stm.setString(8, CARGO_R);
        stm.setInt(9, CELULAR);
        stm.setInt(10, NIT);
        stm.setString(11, ID_NOMBREU);
        stm.setString(12, ID_CONTRASEÑA);

        if (stm.executeUpdate() == 1) {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("errorrr" + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (getConnection() != null) {
                getConnection().close();
            }
            if (stm != null) {
                stm.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("errorrr 2" + e);
        }
    }
```

jsp

```
<table border="0" align="center">

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Pefil</td>
            <td colspan="2"> <select  name="perfil_r" id="perfil_r" required="required"> 
                    <option id="1" value="1" >GERENCIA</option>
                    <option id="2" value="2"> CLIENTE</option>
                    <option id="3" value="3" > EMPEADO</option>

                </select> </td>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No ponga imagenes, es mejor el código para poder replicarlo.
Ponga el código donde está recibiendo los datos y enviadolos a la base de datos, para poder ver claramente donde está el error.

Comment: hola, no me coge el codigo del jsp

Comment: Sí se puede, ponga el código html

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo, todo **option** de un **select**, debe tener su etiqueta de cierre, `<option value="1">Es uno</option>`.

En donde está llamando el método que registra, no le está enviando lo capturado en la lista desplegable.

```
co.registrar(nombre_r, correo_r, nombrecompa_r, 
direccion_r, apellido_r, cargo_R, nombreU_r, contraseña_r, 
0, //aquí es donde debería ir la variable que carga el valor del select
0, 0, 0)
```

Así :

```
co.registrar(nombre_r, correo_r, nombrecompa_r, 
    direccion_r, apellido_r, cargo_R, nombreU_r, contraseña_r, 
    perfil_r, //aquí va la variable
    0, 0, 0)
```

Y al parecer le hace falta los demás datos también.